# Convexity of a set of functions

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a semi-interval split into $d$ disjoint semi-intervals, $\Omega = \bigcup_{j=1}^{d} \Delta_{j}$ , $\Delta_{j}=[\beta_{j-1},\beta_{j})$. An interval translation $T: \Omega \to \Omega$ is a map given by a translation on each $\Delta_{j}$, $T|_{\Delta_{j}}: x \mapsto x+\gamma_{j}$, the vector $(\gamma_{1}, \cdots , \gamma_d)$ is fixed. Here we consider $\Omega$ to be the interval $[0,1)$.

I was reading the paper "Almost every interval translation map o three intervals is finite type" when I faced the following:

> The space $ITM(d)$ of $d$ intervals' translations is a convex polytope in $ \mathbb{R}^{2d-1}$.

For example I know that for $ T \in ITM(1)$ i.e rotation, every point moves by a single $\gamma$. $2(1)-1=1$

If $T\in ITM(2)$ i.e double rotations. every point moves by two $(\gamma_1, \gamma_2)$ and we have another point by which we partition the whole space $\Omega$ i.e if $\Omega=[0,1)$ we could consider it as $\Delta_1=[0,c)$ and $ \Delta_{2}=[c,1)$ so we have another parameter $(c)$. $2(2)-1=3$

Is that what the writer means from convexity of $ITM(d)$ in $ \mathbb{R}^{2d-1}$? how could I show this?

Comment: It is hard to unravel the above.

Comment: @copper.hat What does the writer mean ? Shall I take two maps from $ITM(d)$ and check the convexity relation for them?

Comment: I don't understand why $\Omega$ is partitioned, I don't understand how a translation can map $\Omega \to \Omega$, at that point I give up trying.

Comment: @copper.hat It's how interval translation maps are defined. You could easily take $\Omega=[0,1)$ then partition it into some subintervals depends on the amount of $d$ and then each part is moved by a unique $\gamma$

Comment: If it is a translation then the domain must be unbounded.

Comment: @copper.hat I'm sorry I forgot to add $mod$ for example if $ \Omega = [0,1)$ the translation must be computed in $\text{mod} 1$